# How to get content from another page in uwp after a few seconds

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have Page1.xaml

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="720" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="575">

        <TextBlock Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="28,20,31,0" FontSize="14" Height="145">
            <TextBlock.Transitions>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="400"/>
                </TransitionCollection>
            </TextBlock.Transitions>
            <Run Text="Text 1"/>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And Page2.xaml

```
 <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Foreground="White SelectionChanged="TextBlock_SelectionChanged" 
Name="TextBlockOne">
        <TextBlock.Transitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="400"/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </TextBlock.Transitions>
        <Run Text="Text 2"/>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

What I want to do is to replace "Text 1" in page 1 after 5 seconds with "Text 2" from Page 2.

I tried this in Page2.xaml.cs:

```
private void TextBlock_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var test = TextBlockOne.Text;
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page1), test);
    }
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: whats the problem now?

Comment: Keep a timer for 5 seconds then navigate to page 1  with text value

Comment: The problem right now is that nothing happens. I can't even get text value from page 2

Comment: On Page1.OnNavigatedTo override, you need to get the text from the event args. The test variable is passed into your Page1.OnNavigatedTo method.

Comment: @PedroSilva I tried OnNavigatedTo, but the problem is the timer. Timer seems not work. Navigation work fine, but a want it to navigate after let say 5 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public MainPage()
{
     DispatcherTimer t = new DispatcherTimer();
     t.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
     t.Tick += (s, e) =>
     {
         frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
         StopTimer();
     };
     t.Start();
}

 public void StopTimer()
 {
     t.Stop();
 }
```

Page2.xaml

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock.Text = "My string";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MainPage to Navigate it.

First, the MainPage have a Frame that can navigate to Apage .

Then,MainPage start a Timer that can wait 5 second for call the MainPage to Navigate to Bpage.

The code in xaml ,I write in MainPage

```
<Frame x:Name="frame"/>
```

The code in xaml.cs

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        frame.Navigate(typeof(APage));
        DispatcherTimer t = new DispatcherTimer();
        t.Interval = new TimeSpan(1000);
        t.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            NavigatePageB();
        };
        t.Start();
    }

    private async void NavigatePageB()
    {
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
         () =>
         {
             frame.Navigate(typeof(PageB));
         });
    }
```

Comment: I tried this solution, it only navigates to APage, and doesn't continue to PageB

Comment: @LittleBird It will navigate to PageB after 1 second.

Comment: @LittleBird There is my negligence that write the Frame in NavigatePageB.Please try the code that I changed.

Comment: I tried that solution before, but with TimeSpan(5000). Problem was that it skips over PageA and jumps directly to PageB

Comment: @LittleBird You can use frame.Navigate with argument.